# How can I evaluate value in a row and the value below it using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this df:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c("aa1","aa1","bb1","bb1","cc1","cc1")
y <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
df <- data.frame(y,x)
```

And it looks like this:

```
  y   x
1 1 aa1
2 2 aa1
3 1 bb1
4 2 bb1
5 1 cc1
6 2 cc1
```

How can I, using the dplyr package (mutate), evaluate if the row below has the same value as I want a result like this:

```
  y   x     z
1 1 aa1  TRUE #Comparing from column x the 1st entry vs the 2nd one
2 2 aa1 FALSE #Comparing from column x the 2nd entry vs the 3rd one
3 1 bb1  TRUE #Comparing from column x the 3rd entry vs the 4th one
4 2 bb1 FALSE #...
5 1 cc1  TRUE #...
6 2 cc1 FALSE #...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is lead:

```
 mutate(df, z=x==lead(x))
```

The reverse, btw, is `lag()`

Why do you want to know it, btw? I get the suspicion whatever it is you want to achieve can be done with `group_by()`

Comment: I already used `group_by()`. I want join two dfs, arrange them by group by, then evaluate for duplicates because the first df is tricky and i have to be careful with I discard as duplicate.

Comment: Ok... Well, if you want to share the details, we might be able to come up with a simpler way of achieving your goal. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might even be able to use base R with

```
duplicated(df$x, fromLast = TRUE)
```